# GPS tracking library for Node.js

Tags: library, node.js, gps

I want to create a GPS tracking application for car tracking using GPS trackers, and show the coordinates on a map (km/h, coordinates, etc.).

Please recommend a GPS tracking open source library for node.js that works with any kind of GPS tracker.

I'm using node.js, mongoDB, Google Map(or custom map), socket.io, angular.js.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements, so it might be re-opened.

Comment: I want to see the answer to this question as it would help me. Or, at least to what I think the question is. If you can edit it to give more information then I will be happy to vote to re-open. The more information that you can give us, the more that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry but this all information what I have now

Comment: @RiskeyKey have you found any better library? I have a similar requirement.

Comment: @Rahul_Dabhi not yet :(